# Android DynamoDB mapper.save crash

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to follow the exact DynamoDB example for the Books DB (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html), but my apps crashes at the

```
    mapper.save(book)
```

step (it works if I comment out this line).

Please review below and help me figure out what is the problem. Thank you !

Here is the error message:

> 07-09 20:00:03.652 2458-2458/com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
>   07-09 20:00:03.652 2458-2458/com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
>   07-09 20:00:03.673 2458-2458/com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   07-09 20:00:03.674 2458-2458/com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria, PID: 2458
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria/com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria.SignInActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:128)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:356)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:558)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:444)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:172)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:340)
>                                                                                        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:422)
>                                                                                        at com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria.SignInActivity.BookDBExample(SignInActivity.java:203)
>                                                                                        at com.aegisofsoteria.aegisofsoteria.SignInActivity.onStart(SignInActivity.java:124)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

---

Here is my code:

it is inside

```
    public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
```

and the code is as following :

```
     private void BookDBExample(){
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            my_PollID_here, // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "my ID" + credentialsProvider.getIdentityId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);

    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle("Great Expectations");
    book.setAuthor("Charles Dickens");
    book.setPrice(1299);
    book.setIsbn("1234567890");
    book.setHardCover(false);
    try {
        mapper.save(book);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        // The conditional check failed.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ASE:" + ase.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ACE:" + ace.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
```

Two things that may act as hint:

1. even the error catch can not stop it from crash. Why ?
2. what's the meaning of "No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences" ? I set up the Cognito, IAM, DB exactly as the AWS example, and the only difference is that I can not find "Attach Role Policy" on IAM. The options are "Attach Policy" or "Create Role Policy". So, I have to use "Create Role Policy" to complete that specific step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is NetworkOnMainThreadException. In short, you need to invoke mapper.save() from a background thread, say wrapping it in an AsyncTask.

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.